# Google cloud sql export csv fails when contains nulls

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud, export-csv

I'm exporting a table from my Mysql database in Cloud Sql with the command,

> gcloud sql export csv INSTANCE URI --query = QUERY

I have the file in my bucket, but when I try to import into Bigquery it fails, I noticed that all nulls are replaced by "n,

not even close the quote.

I found that this is a known bug,
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/known-issues

Someone has a temporary solution?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for this issue is still currently being addressed by the Cloud SQL Team. You can stay update on [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/64579566)

If you have to use CSV, you can try using an SQL client to issue an import with the options you prefer ([LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)) instead of using the Cloud SQL import API

Comment: Two years out and this is still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `gcloud sql export csv` API now supports options to workaround this problem.

From: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/import-export-csv#export_data_to_a_csv_file

> Note: Cloud SQL uses double quotes (hex value "22") as the default escape character. This can be a problem for databases where values for NULL are entered as string literals. When importing a file that was exported using the default escape character, the file doesn't treat the value as NULL but as "NULL". We recommend that you use --escape="5C" to override the default when you export the file.

For example, `gcloud sql export csv --escape="5C" INSTANCE URI --query = QUERY`