# google mysql export to csv creates value with single quote

Tags: mysql, export, google-cloud-sql

When using google MySQL and running an export to csv somehow a NULL value is converted to a strange value with an unclosed double quote. See outcome below where a value "N is created.

[image]

When querying the same row in google mysql it looks like:

[image]

Strange thing is, I used the built-in export to csv option and not even an outfile command. Anyone a clue what is happening here and how I can fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is too little information to work with: What does the sheet look like (this line)? Also please do not post images: They can not be searched thus your question can not help others later on.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Apparently it's a bug on Google's export function. So we'll leave it as is for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/64579566).

Please refer to this SO post for a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435419/google-cloud-sql-export-csv-fails-when-contains-nulls).

Comment: Please not that your "issue" links to a MOMA page. It's been a while since I worked there so I can't login anymore ;)